# Convex polyhedron and its Gauß-curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra

I have asked this question on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319912/convex-polyhedron-and-its-gau%C3%9F-curvature) and no one could give me an answer. So I'll post my question here.

What I am trying to prove:

> A convex polyhedron has positive Gauß-Curvature at every vertex.

**What we know:**

- Gauß-Curvature at every vertex is given by $K(p) = 2\pi - \sum\limits_{\text{angle } \alpha_i \text{ around } p} \alpha_i$.
- Gauß-Bonnet state $\sum\limits_{\text{every vertex }p} K(p) = 2\pi\chi(S)$, where $S$ the convex polyhedron. Therefore we can also write$\sum\limits_{\text{every vertex }p} K(p) = 4\pi$.

**My attempt:**

I plugged the Gauß-Curvature in the Gauß-Bonnet-Formula and obtained

$$ 
\sum\limits_{\text{every vertex }p} K(p) = \sum\limits_{\text{every vertex }p} \left(2\pi - \sum\limits_{\text{angle } \alpha_i \text{ around } p} \alpha_i\right) = 4\pi.
$$
Assume now that there exists a $\tilde{p}$ such that $2\pi - \sum\limits_{\tilde{p}} \alpha_i < 0$. Then $2\pi < \sum\limits_{\tilde{p}} \alpha_i$...

From here i do not know how to get further on. Does anyone have an alternative of proving this statement or at least can somebody tell me how to complete my proof?

---

**My attempt is wrong, since the Gauß-formula can also applied for non-convex polyhedra!**

Can someone complete this proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not need Gauss Bonnet to prove the evident fact that sum of angles around a vertex of a convex polytope is less than $2\pi$.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to prove the statement?

Comment: Pick a plane which touches the vertex by not any other part of the polytope. Push it in slightly. Then you have a new polytope formed by the stuff on the side of the plane containing the point. It has the simple form of a planar polygon and one point lying above the polygon with lines connecting to each vertex of the polygon. Project the vertex to the plane, which is a point in the polygon. The plane vertex has angles that sum to $2\pi$. It is easy to see that each angle at the original vertex is strictly smaller than the projected one in the plane.

Comment: @OtisChodosh: Note that if the faces incident to the vertex form a star-shaped polygon on the plane (and the vertex has negative curvature), the original angles are not necessarily smaller than the projected angles.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, are you saying that I used convexity implicitly or that my argument is wrong? Your proof below is very nice, btw :)

Comment: @OtisChodosh: Angles can shrink under projection, even for a convex vertex. This claim needs an example to justify, which I will provide eventually (but not now).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I would be quite interested to see your example!

Comment: @OtisChodosh: Example added at tail-end of post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to sketch a proof of "the evident fact that sum of angles around a vertex of a convex polytope is less than $2\pi$," as phrased by Alexandre Eremenko.
This proof below is more complex than Otis Chodosh's, but perhaps has the advantage
of using convexity explicitly.

Let $v$ be a vertex of the convex polyhedron $P$.
Intersect $P$ with a small sphere $S$ centered on $v$.
The intersection forms a convex spherical polygon $Q$ (blue below)
lying within one hemisphere of $S$.
(The hemisphere rim (red below) corresponds to a plane supporting $P$ at $v$.)
We can take the radius of $S$ to be $1$ by appropriately scaling $P$ prior to
intersecting.
Note that the angles of the faces of $P$ incident to $v$ become the arcs of $Q$.

Now I would like to claim that the perimeter of a convex spherical polygon $Q$
lying within a hemisphere of a unit sphere $S$ is at most $2\pi$.
I will mimic a proof in a
Noam Elkies posting for 
[a planar analog](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71505/6094) of the claim.
The proof is by induction.

Let $Q_0$ be the hemisphere rim; its length is $2\pi$.
$Q_0$ contains $Q$: $Q_0 \supseteq Q$.
We will form a succession of more tightly enclosing convex
spherical polygons, $Q_0 \supseteq Q_1 \supseteq Q_2 \ldots \supseteq Q$,
with decreasing perimeters (more accurately: non-increasing perimeters).

Let $k$ be the number of edges of $Q$ that do not lie along
the boundary of $Q_i$. If $k=0$, then $Q_i=Q$ and we are finished.
Let $e$ be some edge of $Q$ that does not lie on the boundary
of $Q_i$.
Extend $e$ to a great-circle arc that cuts $Q_i$ at points $a$ and $b$.
Define $Q_{i+1}$ as following $Q_i$ but then the "shortcut" $ab$.
Because $ab$ is a geodesic, it is a shortest path between $a$ and $b$,
and therefore cannot be longer than the portion of $Q_i$ cut off.
So the perimeter of $Q_{i+1}$ is at most the perimeter of $Q_i$.
Continuing in this manner produces the nested sequence of
enclosing spherical polygons, ending with $k=0$.

If no edge of $Q$ lies along the original $Q_0$, then
the first cut will be a semicircle (green below), and
the perimeter of $Q_1$ is $\pi+\pi$, i.e., still $2 \pi$.

---

[image: ConvexSphericalPolygon]

---

So the perimeter of $Q$ is
at most $2\pi$, the perimeter of $Q_0$. 
Therefore the sum of the angles of the faces of $P$ incident to $v$
is at most $2\pi$.
Therefore, $P$ has positive angle deficit at $v$, i.e., it has positive Gaussian
curvature there.

Note convexity is used crucially, for a nonconvex spherical polygon could have
an arbitrarily large perimeter, still fitting inside a hemisphere.

---

***Added*** (*2Jul2015*).
The example below is intended to show it is not correct
to project the angles incident to $v$ to a plane and argue that
the angles only enlarge under projection.
Below, one angle is $68^\circ$ incident to $v$ in 3D,
but that angle projects to $45^\circ$ in 2D.

---

[image: ProjectionCex]

---

As you can see, some angles grow, some shrink, under projection.