# Perimeters of nested convex spherical polygons

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra

I seek a reference—not a proof—that if $P_1$ and $P_2$
are two convex polygons on a sphere composed of geodesic segments,
contained in a hemisphere, and
$P_1 \subseteq P_2$, then the perimeter of $P_1$ is $\le$ the perimeter of
$P_2$.
This is a spherical variant of the analogous claim in the plane, which was
proved by Noam Elkies in [an earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71505/6094).
I know how to prove the spherical version mimicking Noam's proof;
the essence was used [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/210588/6094).

---

[image]

---

I need to use this claim in a paper, and I'd prefer to cite a reference 
rather than include my own proof.