# Bounding the area of a convex body bounded in a sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have a question which I believe to be pretty basic.

Let $\Gamma$ be some convex body, bounded inside a $L_2$ sphere of radius 1 $B(0,1)$.

Is it true that the surface area of $\Gamma$ is smaller than the surface area of the sphere?

I'm guessing that the answer involves finding a continuous deformation from $\Gamma$ to the sphere for which the area is monotonous, but I'm incapable of finding it

Comment: See Noam Elkies answer to "[Circumference of Convex Shapes](http://mathoverflow.net/q/71502/6094)" for the 2D versions of your question.

Comment: I think for $\mathbb{R}^3$ at least, you can use [Crofton's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula), coupled with the 2D result.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58456/surface-area-of-a-convex-set-less-than-that-of-its-enclosing-sphere

Answer (score 20):

The nearest-point projection from the sphere to the convex set decreases distances.

Comment: This is a very elegant answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the metric projection surjective?

Comment: @user60933, the normal of any supporting hyperplane at a point $p$ of the compact set will meet the sphere in a point whose image under the nearest-point projection is $p$.

Answer (score 6):

This is a consequence of the standard inequalities on the "intrinsic volumes" (or "quermaß integrals", the two are synonymous up to a constant) of convex sets: for every $i$, the $i$-th intrinsic volume $V_i(K)$ of a convex set is monotone in $K$, and for a $d$-dimensional convex set, $V_{d-1}(K)$ is twice the $(d-1)$-dimensional surface area of $K$ (while $V_d(K)$ is the $d$-dimensional volume; the quick definition in general is that $V_i(K)$ is the coefficient of $r^{d-i}$ in the polynomial giving the volume of the distance $r$ ball $K+B(0,r)$ around $K$, divided by the volume of $B(0,1)$ in dimension $d-i$).

See, for example, J. R. Sangwine-Yager's chapter "Mixed Volumes" (specifically §3) in the *Handbook of Convex Geometry* (vol. A), edited by Gruber & Wills (North-Holland 1993).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a general fact. If $K_1\subset K_2$ are convex, then the surface area
of $K_1$ is at most that of $K_2$.